# JavaFX Stage drag events (drag started, ended, moved, etc.)

Tags: events, javafx-2, javafx-8, mouseevent, drag

I need to listen to drag events for the Stage. It's a regular decorated Stage. I'm dragging the window/stage over the desktop and need to listen to observe the dragging process, like when it started, when ended and what was the locations for these events and the drag-move events in the middle.

Is it possible for javafx.stage.Stage? I can achieve sth like that by using JFrame with JFXPanel (as JFrame supports such events) but would rather like to avoid such solution.

Comment: Would registering listeners with the stage's [`xProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#xProperty), `yProperty`, `widthProperty` and `heightProperty` work?

Comment: I've tried that, it's not enough to get consistent "drag" state. Drag operation is combination of mouse down (for "drag start"), then mouse mouse down + mouse move (for "drag move") then mouse up (for drag end). All three of them need to be "connected" and "consistent" - I mean they need to be executed in the right order. It would be hard to achieve. Anyway, I have problems with mouse event listener for Stage too. It seems for me that JavaFX has no control over the window which is OS specific window.

Comment: You are correct in the last sentence. The `Stage` itself is implemented by the native windowing toolkit; there is no hook in JavaFX into the events on that stage you are interested in. The only way forward I could see would be to use an undecorated window and implement the decorations, and mouse drag listeners on them, yourself, which I suspect is not a route you want to go down....